# e.force:navigateToSObject is behaving strangely

Tags: lightning-aura-components, redirect

I am trying to navigate the user to the record detail page of selected account and opportunity.
For this, I have written a lightning component named : **RedirectToWizard**

Component code is

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride" 
                access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordName" type="String"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="{!c.handleChange}">{!v.recordName}</a>
</aura:component>
```

controller code is

```
({
    handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId=component.get("v.recordId");
        var sObectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        //alert(recordId);
        sObectEvent .setParams({
            "recordId": recordId,
            "slideDevName": "detail"
        });
        sObectEvent.fire(); 
    }
})
```

Now I'm using this component in many components as :

```
<c:RedirectToWizard recordId="{!i.Id}" recordName="{!i.First_Name__c+ ' ' +i.Last_Name__c}"/>
```

Problem is when I click on the link to redirect, for the first time, it's redirecting me to the standard home page and when I move back(clicking back button on the browser) then it's redirecting me to the record detail page as it supposed to.

I also tried to know the record Id passed to RedirectToWizard component(using alert). Every time it's giving the correct alert but behaving the same way as I told earlier.

Sometimes it's redirecting properly also. But it's 1 out of 100 only.

Can anyone guide me on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried dropping down the API version of the lightning component, could be a potential bug

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Try that additionally it looks like there is some problems with it as you can see here
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3pcAAC